# Nuget package error in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I'm getting an error in Visual studio 2017 when I build the solution.

"The package ComponentAce.Compression.Libs.zlib with version 1.0.4 could not be found in C:\Users\.nuget\packages. Run a NuGet package restore to download the package.".

My code is in .net 4.7.2 (C#,WPF)

I tried to install/uninstall/rebuild/clean and I also completely removed any references to that package in my code. Nothing's working. Any idea what's the issue here?

Comment: Hi, what's the vs version do you use?  I mean Help=>About  VS... Then you can find the current version, for now, the latest one is [15.9.16](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes), please update your vs to latest version to check if it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Trouble-shooting nuget issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore-troubleshooting#other-potential-conditions).

1. You can clean the cache by VS IDE (Go Tools => Options => Nuget Package Manager => Settings => Clear Nuget caches). After that, clean and build current project again.
2. If the issue persists, open your Solution directory => close VS instance => delete the .vs folder, and delete the bin and obj folders in Project directory. Then rebuild the project.
3. If all above not helps, it could be one similar issue [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/312662/restore-nuget-packages-does-nothing-after-cache-cl.html), [update VS2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) to latest 15.9.16 to fix it.

**Update**:

> could not be found in C:\Users.nuget\packages

1.What does the specific path looks like? It should be `C:\user\user-name\.nuget\packages` [by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders), if the error you got is `C:\Users\.nuget\packages`, I think you may have a custom [nuget.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section) file which causes this issue.

2.Also, you may create a new empty project and installing the missing packages in that project. Than closed the empty project, reopened the original one to run a rebuild. Hint from [marco6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920633/the-package-could-not-be-found-in-c-users-username-nuget-packages-run-a-nuge).

Comment: Thank you @Lance. But where do I find the ".vs folder"? I'm not seeing anything like that.

Comment: In solution folder, that's a hidden folder so you may need to enable the `View=>Hidden Items` in `windows File system` to see it.

Comment: @David I saw your commented above that you've enabled the option, the [two options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#enable-and-disable-package-restore-in-visual-studio)? Also, I will update my answer with some more tips you can check and try.

Comment: Thank you Lance. I cleared the nuget Cache and I also had to delete the ".vs" folder and rebuild for it to work.

Comment: Glad to know it makes some help :)

Answer (score -1):

Enable 'Allow Nuget to download missing packages' under Tools -> Options

[image]

Comment: That option is enabled.

Comment: This is usually enabled in new installs of VS, so unless manually disabled, this won't be of any help....