# How to prioritize c# code errors over Razor view errors when upgrading .Net versions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0, episerver, .net-4.7

I am currently performing my 3rd .Net upgrade from .Net4.7 to .Net6.0. The reason I am continually updating from those specific .Net versions is because this is an Optimizely CMS/Commerce web-app upgrade. However, the errors I am experiencing seem to be .Net related so I am posting here instead of an Optimizely specific forum.

To do an upgrade I run the following command:

`upgrade-assistant upgrade pathTo/projFile.csproj --ignore-unsupported-features --skip-backup --non-interactive --extension "C:\Temp\EPi.Source.Updater.1.0.32" --target-tfm-support LTS`

Once that is complete I massage the .csproj file/utilize the Nuget Package Manager to satisfy dependencies and then I start to fix code errors and determine how to best address areas that need to be re-architected due to changes in .Net.

However, this time around, my compiler is only showing me errors in `.cshtml` files. This is not the case with the previous .Net6 upgrades I've completed.

I do not like this because there are certain things, such as `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>`, which are no longer present in .Net6 that I need to re-architect at a code level before I can fix at a Razor view level.

When I try and figure out how to solve this I've come across a few idiosyncrasies:

1. When I would open up a `.cs` file I would get errors like: `Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73910037/1798381) answer from a related post was the cause (I think). Since then I've been cognizant to not have multiple VS instances running, something I've previously been able to do without issue.

2. I added the following snippet to my `.csproj` file to try and get the compiler to build `.cs` files first:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RazorCompileOnBuild>false</RazorCompileOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

3. I have repaired, then uninstalled, deleted some VS app data files, and reinstalled my IDEs. I used to have VS 2022 Preview as my primary IDE and still had VS 2019 installed. Now both are gone and I just have VS 2022 (non-preview).
4. I have gone back to our original solution and upgraded it again. This time I updated my `.Net Upgrade Assistant`. In doing so I had to update my command to the following as the previous one no longer worked: `upgrade-assistant upgrade pathTo/projFile.csproj` which is slightly annoying because I no longer get the work done by the `Epi.Source.Updater` extension.

This helped a little, after the command ran, I replaced the .csproj file from my initial upgrade so I didn't have to fix the dependency issues again. The next build I got ~350 code errors! Success, or so I thought. I then replaced the views folder from my old upgrade so that I didn't lose the `.cshtml` updates my team made while I was trying to figure this out. Then it went back to square one. So, I did a 3rd upgrade and I never got that intermediate build where I was presented with code errors.

So, in the end I feel that my processes were identical yet I got different results each time so I figured I would ask the web and see if you guys have any advice?

Comment: Your issue likely stems from inconsistent compilation and multiple VS instances. Quick tips:


1. **Compilation**: Use `<RazorCompileOnBuild>false</RazorCompileOnBuild>` to compile `.cs` files first.
  

2. **IDE Setup**: Ensure VS 2022 has all required SDKs.


3. **Cache**: Clear `obj` and `bin` folders.


4. **Extension**: Check for an updated Epi.Source.Updater.


5. **Logs**: Use verbose logs for hidden issues.


Consider a minimal example to debug separately.